# Why is there a voltage drop across an inductor?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, inductance

If there is one coulomb of charge passing through the inductor, and one volt is supplied to that coulomb, what happens to the 1 joule of energy as it goes through the inductor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one volt is supplied to that coulomb

The implication here is that it requires the expenditure of 1 joule of energy to move 1 coulomb of charge through an inductor.
If the inductor is ideal and the current is steady this is not true as it takes no work to move a charge though an ideal inductor.

Only if the current (rate of flow of charge) is changing will work have to be done to move charges though an ideal inductor.
In the case of the current increasing you can think of the work done resulting in an increase in the energy stored in the magnetic field produced by the inductor.

Another possibility is that the inductor has a resistance and then work has to be done to drive a charge through the inductor even if the current is steady.
In this case the work done ends up as heat.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in the magnetic field. When the voltage is taken away the current keeps flowing for some time untill the magnetic field is exhausted.